# XrmToolBox Error while deserializing configuration file. Details: There is an error in XML document (13, 8) at ConnectionManager

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, xrm, dataverse

An unexpected error occurred:

> System.Exception: Error while deserializing configuration file. Details: There is an error in XML document (13, 8). at McTools.Xrm.Connection.ConnectionManager.loadConnectio nslistO at McTools.Xrm.Connection.ConnectionManager..ctor0 at McTools.Xrm.Connection.ConnectionManager.< > c.<.cctor> b_ _70_00 at System.LazitCreateValue0 at System.Lazyl.lazylnitValueO at XrmToolBox.New.NewForm.ManageConnectionControl0 at XrmToolBox.New.NewForm..ctor(Stringl] args) at XrmToolBox.Program.Main(String0 args)
>
> One reason can be that at least one file is locked by Windows. Please unblock each locked files or unlock XrmToolBox.zip before extracting its content

Comment: Provide a bit more information around what you are doing, share some example code too, to reproduce this issue if you can.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @IgorMeszaros after updating XrmToolBox. The tool was showing up this error on load and would not open. I can open the tool by deleting the connections document.
But removing the date property ("LastUsedOn") in the ConnectionsList.Default.xml file. I could open the tool without losing my connections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open %APPDATA%\MscrmTools\XrmToolBox\Connections\ConnectionsList.Default.xml
replace all LastUsedOn nodes
Regular expression:
\n?[\S\s\n]*?</LastUsedOn>\n?
Use this to find and replace all with blank